# How to use old Windows 7 install in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I have decieded to convert my Windows 7 laptop to Ubuntu. I virtualized the Windows 7 install and I thought I read that there is a way to launch the apps that are in my Windows 7 VHD inside Ubuntu using VMware in some way. Am I correct or do I just have to run my old Windows 7 as a VM through VirtualBox/VMware?

Answer (score 0):

The best and most popular Windows emulator is Wine. As far as i know, VMware doesn't have a linux version.
Here's their guide to installing it [winhq tutorial](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Comment: Sure, there is a Linux version of VMware: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0

Comment: Wine is not an emulator.  It's a compatibility layer which allows a number of Windows programs to run on Linux. It's far from perfect however, lots of Windows software does not run.  Vitalization software such as VMware is Virtualbox is a better option but does require install media and Windows licence.